# How to stop Sound , Howler.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, howler.js

I am using howler to play sound on some event. The sound start fine and for stopping it I am using `sound.unload()` , the problem is when next time I start playing same sound its volume is increased from previous time, and 3rd time it is higher than second time.

Why it this happening.

my code for calling howlerjs is

```
    //jquery plugin start

window.sound = new Howl({
    src: ['audio/'+settings.soundSrc],
    volume:1
});


//--other code--
onSomeEvent(){
    window.sound.play();
}

//jquery plugin ends

//stopping sound from main event
window.sound.unload();
```

Comment: Why are you stopping with `unload` rather than `stop`?

Comment: @JamesSimpson, both unload and stop are showing same behaviour, as related to my problem.